# trying to find db connection leak in my code, using Spring / JPA / Hikari

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hikaricp, jpa

I've got a problem with a Spring web application that periodically runs into an error fetching a connection from my connection pool. Eventually in the logs I see entries like:

- Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
- Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.

Only way to recover I've found once it hits this point is to restart Tomcat.

I think the most likely explanation is I have some code somewhere that is not properly cleaning up its connection - returning it to Hikari, leaving something open so Spring can't clean it up, etc.

To troubleshoot I've set my hikari config leakDetectionThreshold to 5000ms and enabled logging. After that, I see log entries like

```
2018-04-24 19:53:56 WARN  ProxyLeakTask:87 - Connection leak detection 
triggered for org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@664ec666, stack trace 
follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1940)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:981)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1444)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:379)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.web.jpa.util.DBHelper.getPagedMappedDbResults(DBHelper.java:76)
    at com.mycompany.web.jpa.repository.TaskRepositoryImpl.findTaskDetailsByStepIdAndIdIn(TaskRepositoryImpl.java:245)
......
```

So it is detecting a possible leak. Could be a false positive I suppose? But this is also the only class in my app that is doing database access outside of the standard service/repository pattern often used in Spring apps, so it seems like a likely culprit, and it's my best lead at the moment.

Anyway, the last piece of non library code I see in the trace (ie stuff I wrote, so most likely to be the cause of the leak!) is my DBHelper::getPagedMappedDbResults method, relevant bit included here:

```
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(countQueryText);
    setQueryParameters(q, parameters);
    long numActualResults = 0;
    try {
        numActualResults = ((Number)q.getSingleResult()).longValue(); // line 76
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("just in case: " + e);
    }
```

So basically I create a Query object from my EntityManager instance, set some parameters, and run it to get some results.

Is there something I need to be doing with a Query object when I'm done with it? q.cleanup()? I don't see anything like this from reading the docs, but am I not doing good housekeeping on this resource?

The entityManager itself is created from an @Autowired annotation. My understanding is if I didn't "new" it to instantiate it and instead let the Spring framework autowire it, then Spring will do whatever cleanup is necessary. Is that right? Or do I need to be doing some cleanup after I use the entityManager?

Version details:

- Tomcat 8 / Java 8
- Spring 5.0.0.RELEASE
- Spring Data Kay-RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.2.3.Final
- Hikari 2.4.5

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There isn't anything you need to do to release the query object. It's lifecycle is supposed to be managed by the library. If this is the cause of the connection leak, I'd point to your version of hibernate as having a bug. I'd suspect it was in NativeQueryImpl.doList(). Everything below there looks pretty much like every hibernate stack trace I've ever seen. You could try detaching the object returned by getSingleResult(), but I'm pretty sure that would throw an exception since it is not a defined entity.

Answer (score 0):

What is the query? Is it heavy? Maybe you have deadlock here? Connection management looks fine. You do not acquire connection explicitly, so no need to release it. The query might be long running so Hibernate is not able to complete it and release the connection.

Also, you can check the number of open connections on the DB side. Do some analysis on that side as well.